# How the Iterator methods are called upon iterating object through foreach

Tags: php, iterator

I gone through the [Iterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php) and got why it should be used but the thing I didn't get is how the methods of iterator class called upon iterating the object through foreach.

Consider the below example copied from php manual page

```
class myIterator implements Iterator {
    private $position = 0;
    private $array = array(
        "firstelement",
        "secondelement",
        "lastelement",
    );  

    public function __construct() {
        $this->position = 0;
    }

    function rewind() {
        var_dump(__METHOD__);
        $this->position = 0;
    }

    function current() {
        var_dump(__METHOD__);
        return $this->array[$this->position];
    }

    function key() {
        var_dump(__METHOD__);
        return $this->position;
    }

    function next() {
        var_dump(__METHOD__);
        ++$this->position;
    }

    function valid() {
        var_dump(__METHOD__);
        return isset($this->array[$this->position]);
    }
}
```

Here I want to understand that when I used foreach as below.

How the methods of myIterator class called automatically?

```
$it = new myIterator;

foreach($it as $key => $value) {
    var_dump($key, $value);
    echo "\n";
}
```

What is the magic here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "magic", if you want to call it that, is simply that PHP has a defined behaviour when you try to iterate using an object that implements the `Iterator` interface.

An interface, as you may know, is simply a contract between the programmer and the application that says that certain methods will be defined. If a class is defined without implementing the methods in the interface, PHP will throw a fatal error and the program will terminate. This means that when a `foreach` encounters an object that implements the `Iterable` interface, that object is guaranteed to have methods called `current`, `key`, `next`, `rewind` and `valid`.

With the exception of valid, these are all methods that exist for normal arrays as well, albeit as procedural functions rather than object methods. (`valid` doesn't exist for arrays because the functions that select a new item will return the item, so you can say that `valid` is baked into those functions.) This shows that, under the hood, a `foreach` loop works in more or less the same way on both arrays and `Iterable` objects.

The process for iterating over an `Iterable` object is show, or at least implied, in the example on the [manual page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php) you linked in your question, but I can see how it might be confusing. Here's a basic explanation of the process:

In general, a `foreach` loop will reset the pointer for an iterable (notice the small I here - I'm referring to either an array or an object that implements the `Iterable` interface) back to its first position. In other words, it "rewinds" the iterable in the same way that you would rewind a tape - a concept that might be lost on the younger generation. As you might imagine, this is the `rewind` method that the interface requires.

Once the array is rewound, the `foreach` attempts to read whatever element is currently selected. The data for the current element is retrieved using the `current` method, and the key for the element is retrieved using the `key` method. These items are placed into the variables you define in the `foreach` loop and the loop runs its iteration.

After your loop iteration completes, `foreach` will try to grab the next element by using the `next` method. It then processes the loop by doing the same steps as in the last paragraph.

On an `Iterable` object, before reading any data using `current` and `key`, the `foreach` loop will call the `valid` method. If this method returns `FALSE`, or a value that PHP considers equivalent to it (like 0 or `NULL`), `foreach` assumes there is nothing more to process and exits the loop entirely, and your program continues as normal.

Answer (score 1):

There is no magic. `foreach` will simply check if an object implements the Iterator interface and then call the appropriate methods in the right order.

You might find some more details in here: http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_4/Zend/zend_interfaces.c